# The ttl process of mongodb passes 0

Tags: mongodb, ttl

Good afternoon. 
I have a problem with the TTL indices of Mongodb. It does not run correctly.

A TTL index has been created to a Date field and the documents have not been deleted once the time has expired.
It seems that the problem is that it does not work correctly.
When making a:
db.serverStatus (). metrics.ttl
Bring back:
passes: 0

But if the TTL is enabled.
db.adminCommand ({setParameter: 1, ttlMonitorEnabled: true});

Doing the same in localhost works but in the server where this mongodb does not work.
Therefore I do not know what the problem may be.

Comment: Did you set up the remote MongoDB server or is this is a hosted service? If a hosted service, what provider & plan are you using? What is the output of `db.version()` via the `mongo` shell?

Comment: The machine is located on an Amazon Linux server. The output is:"version" : "4.0.4"

Comment: Have you tried restarting the `mongod` server? The TTL monitor thread is enabled by default and `db.serverStatus (). metrics.ttl.passes` should be incrementing every minute even if you don't have TTL indexes defined. You can doublecheck TTL monitor is enabled with `db.adminCommand ({getParameter: 1, ttlMonitorEnabled: true})`, but unless you have stopped or killed this thread it should be running.

Comment: I get this error when I restart:                                                     WARNING: mongod started without --replSet yet 1 documents are present in local.system.replset.", 
Database contents may appear inconsistent with the oplog and may appear to not contain", 
 writes that were visible when this node was running as part of a replica set.", 
Restart with --replSet unless you are doing maintenance and no other clients are connected.", 
The TTL collection monitor will not start because of this.", 
For more info see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/ttlcollections",

Comment: Ah, that explains the issue. If this member is part of a replica set the TTL Monitor thread will be disabled in standalone mode to prevent data changes that would make this member inconsistent (since changes in standalone mode are not written to the replication oplog). It sounds like you are already making changes in standalone mode so probably want to drop the `local` database to remove the replica set configuration and oplog.